# Not able to initialize Uint8Array from an ArrayBuffer received via postMessage

Tags: typescript, arraybuffer, typed-arrays, uint8array

I have a main web-page which contains an iframe hosting another page (both are in same domain).

1. The main-page exposes an application object <`myApp`> and an api <`myAPI`> which receives an ArrayBuffer.

`myApp.myPI(new Uint8Array([255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0 , 255, 0, 255, 0]));`
This is how I call it from Console in DevTools.

2. The API, after receiving the call, json-stringifies the whole data for the postMessage and posts Message to the child iframe.
3. Iframe has a handler which  then does a json-parse to forward the data to the right handler <`func myMessageDataHandler(buffer: ArrayBuffer)`>. Json-parse does read the ArrayBuffer back to an `ArrayBuffer` type of object.
4. Then <`func myMessageDataHandler(buffer: ArrayBuffer)`> receives the processed ArrayBuffer and does the following

`let inputArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);`

if I peek into `buffer` at this point, I do see the values as expected, but `inputArray` fails to copy any data from `buffer`. In debug mode, If I see the type of `buffer` it says `Object` however in my TypeScript code, the buffer param is still of type `ArrayBuffer`. If you notice in the screenshot, no ArrayBuffer APIs is working like `slice`

There seems to be some **type** mess-up. I have even tried explicitly casting but doesn't help

`let inputArray = new Uint8Array(buffer as ArrayBuffer);`

[image]

Comment: `buffer` looks like an object there, an object with sequential keys that each have a byte as their value. Remember that types only exist at compile time, so `as SomeType` does nothing to the compiled javascript. Which means somewhere something is getting messed up. Try asking the `.constructor` property to get a better idea of what these objects are at each step. `(new Uint8Array([])).constructor //=> Uint8Array() { [native code] }`

Comment: thanks Alex. i was eventually able to get the arraybuffer with appropriate type by bypassing the JSON.stringify/parse. I used the Transfer method of post Message